# Grouping message in Sentry

Tags: sentry

Using Sentry 7.7, on premise with Docker. Everything is fine, but message grouping is weird:

[image]

They are same events, with just a message and a timestamp, but they are not grouped all together, why?

Comment: Sentry groups by the structured data in the message. What's likely true here is either it has no useful data to group by, or the version you're using does not handle a certain edgecase. See here for details: https://docs.getsentry.com/hosted/learn/rollups/

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @David,

Using fingerprint (https://docs.getsentry.com/on-premise/learn/rollups/#custom-grouping) gives total control on grouping, excellent!